# How can I save the position of a Drag and Drop image after refreshing the page

Tags: html5-canvas

I want to do with this is that, whenever im going to drag and resize the images it will save the position or it will still remain if im going to refresh the page. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your positions in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) on event of [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) this is called before page is refreshed.

> The localStorage property allows you to access a local Storage object.
>   localStorage is similar to sessionStorage. The only difference is
>   that, while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data
>   stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the browsing session
>   ends—that is, when the browser is closed.

```
localStorage.setItem('somekey',JSON.stringify(positionData)); 
// stringify if your data is an object.
```

and then on load of page reposition them by reading the values from the `localStorage`

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('somekey',positionData);
if(data) var position = JSON.parse(data); // parse string to get object
else{
    //Do normal logic
}
```